# Firebase Auth Web - Google sign in - not presenting pick account dialog on android

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi when im using firebase auth and with google sign in, im not getting this dialog as the picture.

When im going to google.com from the browser and click sign in so im getting this dialog.

is it possible to make firebase auth to present it as well?

i tried to use one tap, but it didnt work on android as well

example of code to implement

https://github.com/brunocrosier/google-one-tap/blob/master/pages/index.js

check index page to add

and check useGoogleOneTap.ts to see implementation

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how is your question related to Android?

Comment: because its happening only in android?

Comment: So you say that you're trying to sign in via the web browser and you don't get the "pick account dialog"?

Comment: yes. when im going to google.com its working, but when im using firebase auth web its not

Comment: What is the code that you're using in Android, that produces that behavior? Since you're using Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) might help, right?

Comment: its web not kotlin